# CSS style formatting

Tags: css

My footer and its content do not re-position proportional to each other when I reduce the height of the footer.

CSS code:

```css
#footer {
    clear: right;
    background: #d1dceb;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 70%;
    float: right;
    height: 5px;
}

#footer p.left {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#footer p.right {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

And this is what I am getting:

[image]

Anything I should do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height` and add `overflow: hidden`:

```css
#footer
{
    clear: right;
    background: #d1dceb;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 70%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: No luck with both suggestions, and removing height increases the height of the footer.

Comment: Right. What is the expected output? Can you post a pic/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

just before footer div ends and also try removing height from footer

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're not adding any context and any HTML markup. But this is important:

```
#footer {
    clear: right; /* why are you doing this? **/
    background: #d1dceb;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 70%;
    float: right; /* why are you doing this? **/
    height: 5px;
}
```

take a look at those commented lines, which quite probably you don't need at all.

Now, into your issue, you can use two options:

**1) clear floats by using the "clearfix" method:** simply add an empty div that clears the floats of preceding elements, like this:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

and then in CSS:

```
.clearfix{clear:both; float:none;}
```

Obviously you can use this as many times as you want since you're using re-usable classes.

**The option 2 is as follows:**

```
#footer p.right:after {content:'';clear:both; float:none; }
```

What we do here is to add some "empty" content, yet we assign it a `"clear:both"` property to clear everything, more or less as if we have added that div in **option 1**

Of course **option 1** is way better, but well, there you go

Answer (score 0):

You're using float to position elements, which means that the height of the floated elements are set to 0, just like if you're using `positioning: absolute`. DON'T use floats! Use flex.

```css
#footer {
    background: #d1dceb;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto; /* center element */
}

#footer p {
  flex: 1 1 auto; /* fill up the entire available space */
}

#footer p.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <p>Left footer element</p>
  <p class="right">Right footer element</p>
</div>
```